# pars xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I need to get youtube video description by passing an id using python. I use this:

```
r = requests.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/UuupUqDO98s?v=2").content
```

then I need to get the title,etc. What I have done as suggested by google surfing is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('id.xml')
root2=tree.getroot()
y=root2.iter('published').attrib
```

here said there is no attribute

```
elements=ElementTree.parse('id.xml')
root=elements.getroot()
print root.getchildren()
root.find("id")

print elements.findall('entry').find('./id').text
```

none of them worked .
the only thing that worked finr for me is:

```
print root.getchildren()[25].get('viewCount')
```

but I want to get them by tag not index.

Can you advise me on that?
Do you know any other way to get the description?

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be a better idea to just use the official [GData Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/).